# handsOnTable cell coloring

Tags: jquery, handsontable

I have a Handsontable table filled with data and already rendered

After checking the cells, I have located a couple of cells of interest and would like to color them - is there a good way to do this using the Handsontable code?

Please note this is after loading and rendering the table

Edit:

The table is rendered with basic options:

```
$container.handsontable({
    startRows: 8,
    startCols: 6,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    minSpareCols: 1,
    //contextMenu: false,
    cells: function (row, col, prop) {
    }
  });
```

And the data is loaded via Ajax, decode_file.php reads an excel sheet and returns data as JSON:

```
  $.ajax({
      url: "decode_file.php",
      type: 'GET',
      success: function (res) {
        handsontable.loadData(res.data);
        console.log('Data loaded');
      },
      error: function (res) {
        console.log("Error : " + res.code);
      }
    });
```

After loading the data, the user clicks a "Process" button and the code looks for a cell with the text "Hello world". Let's say the code finds the text "Hello World" in cell **row 4/col 5** and changed the background color of cell **row 4/col 5** to **red**

Comment: On what criteria do you want them coloured, how are you using `handsOnTable()` (whatever that is, *link us to the plugin you're using*)? What's your (representative/[short, self-contained, example (SSCCE)](http://sscce.org/)? Can you show a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) to reproduce your problem, and show what you're doing?

Comment: let me see if I can run it on jsFiddle, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The homepage provides a good example for your purpose:

http://handsontable.com/demo/renderers.html

Just modify the condition (in this case upper/left corner).

```
cells: function (row, col, prop) {
  if (row === 0 && col === 0) {
    return {type: {renderer: greenRenderer}};
  }
}
```

and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

1. get the coordinates of the selected cell(s) using handsontable('getSelected')
2. if the selection is not empty :

   a. loop on all cells to gather each cell's renderer using handsontable('getCellMeta') and meta.renderer, then store them in an array (this should be done only once)

   b. update the table using handsontable("updateSettings") and cellProperties.renderer :

   - for cells within the selected coordinates, apply the chosen renderer and update the renderer's name in the 2.a. array
   - for all other cells, apply the stored renderer

Answer (score 0):

One a bit strange method that I'm using, and it actually fast and works fine:

```
afterRender: function(){
    render_color(this);
}
```

ht is the instance of the handsontable, and render_color:

```
function render_color(ht){
  for(var i=0;i<ht.countRows();i++){
    for(var p=0;p<ht.countCols();p++){
      cell_color = "#000";
      font_color = "#fff";
      $(ht.getCell(i,p)).css({"color": font_color, "background-color": cell_color})
    }
  }
}
```