# Handsontable coloring cells using button

Tags: handsontable

I want to allow the user to color selected cells by clicking a button (say, red, green and blue buttons).

To get the selected cells I found this code:

```js
$('div#example1').handsontable(options);

//get the instance using jQuery wrapper
var ht = $('#example1').handsontable('getInstance');

//Return index of the currently selected cells as an array [startRow, startCol, endRow, endCol]
var sel = ht.getSelected();

//'alert' the index of the starting row of the selection
alert(sel[0]);
```

But I can't run this code when clicking a button, because the selection "disappear" after clicking and before the function starts to run.

I try following [this instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16945594/1223457) but I need a workaround this issue.

Answer (score 1):

please add `outsideClickDeselects: false,` to your options in constructor and you can perform the 'ht.getSelected()' method.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `afterSelectionEnd` event to store the selection in a hidden field?

Then when pressing the button, you highligh/color the cells using the hidden selection info.

Would that work?

Comment: Hey thanks for the idea. Before I try it, I need to find a way to save the color chosen to the DB, and to extract and render it properly later on. I'll post here once I have the solution.